# Текстовый документом не показывается на эмуляторе

Tags: android-studio

Текстовый (`txt`) документ не показывается на эмуляторе. Путь тоже показывается неверно.

Код:

```
 try {
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("C://Users/Romashov/AndroidStudioProjects/KG-RUDictionary/app/src/main/assets/dictionary.txt")));
    String mline;
    int i=0;

    while ((mline =reader.readLine())!= null) {
        String[] lineData= mline.split("-");
        data.add(new DictionaryModel(""+i,lineData[0],lineData[1]));
        i++;
    }
    reader.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Не нужно задавать вопрос еще раз, достаточно отредактировать [предыдущий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/822122/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android-studio-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-txt-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0).

Comment: Если путь показывается неверно, значит надо отредактировать путь.